# Flex CSS Blocking bottom content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

wonder if anyone can help me. I use the following code the display content in a div however whenever I load the data into the DIV it loads fine and the scroll bar appears. However, the last result is always half displayed.
If I add a spacer like below, it fixes the issue, and I can scroll beyond the last result.

```
<div style="height:300px;"></div
```

However, that's not pretty so my question is does display: flex allow you to add a bottom buffer of 200px somehow? I had a good read of https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ but couldn't find a solution.

Full Code

```css
.headerbar {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#titlebar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90px;
  background-image: url(images/logo_new.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

#mainpage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 92px;
}

.leftsidemain {
  background-color: #27383f;
  width: 50%;
  height: 850px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.pagearea {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 850px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbar">
  <div id="titlebar"></div>
</div>

<div id="mainpage">
  <div class="leftsidemain"></div>
  <div class="pagearea"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your all code.

Comment: @Dogukan Cavus done thanks i've added the basics of how it's layed out and tried to keep it simple with the code example.

Comment: @CliveAtkins, unfortunately this code doesn't demonstrate problem you've described. Please check why `#mainpage` element has fixed height value. Also do you have styles for your block of content at the bottom (which has problems)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header element (`.headerbar`) has a child (`#titlebar`) set to `height: 90px`. That sets the height of the header.

Your main content element (`#mainpage`) is set to `height: 600px`. Well, that will overflow the screen when the viewport is shorter than 690px.

Instead of `height: 600px` try `height: calc(100vh - 90px)`.

Also, set the `overflow` on the parent, so the scrollbar activates when the child overflows.

```css
.headerbar {
  background: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#titlebar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90px;
  background-image: url(images/logo_new.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

#mainpage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 100%;
  /* height: 600px; */
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 92px;
    height: calc(100vh - 90px); /* new */
    overflow: auto;             /* new */
}

.leftsidemain {
  background-color: #27383f;
  width: 50%;
  height: 850px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.pagearea {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 850px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="headerbar">
  <div id="titlebar"></div>
</div>
<div id="mainpage">
  <div class="leftsidemain"></div>
  <div class="pagearea"></div>
</div>
```